# How to add title attribute for <a> tags to show tooltips for wordpress paginate_links function

Tags: wordpress, pagination, attributes

In order to enhance user-experience i’d like to add the title attribute to the «a» tags in the paginate_links. For the class «page-numbers» a title like «page X» and for the class «next» a title like «next page».
I’am using paginate_links function:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $ppframe,
            'category_name' => $cat_id,
            'paged' => $paged,
            );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            echo '<div class="archiv-pager">';
            echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
            'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'before_page_number' => '',
            'after_page_number'  => ' • '
            ));
            echo '</div>';
```

I’ve searched the wordpress documentation and also various tutorials about paginate_links but couldn’t find a hint how to add the title attribute to the a tags of the paginate links. Is there a specific argument for paginate_links function or some other method to add the title attribute? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: See this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/#comment-3862)

Comment: Yes, this example allows to add title tags to the a tags, but is rather difficult to achieve the same convenience as the built in paginate_links function. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: A more flexible solution: [link](https://kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin) Case closed.